# When creating a lightning-record-edit-form with two columns, the fields are not occupying the full width of the page

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, lightning-design-system, lightning-recordeditform

I have created a lightning-record-edit-form with two columns, but in the UI, the fields are not occupying the full width of the page. I have tried various approaches, including using SLDS, layout items, and setting margins, but nothing seems to work. Please find the screenshot below of my page. As you can see, there is a lot of space between and around the fields.
[image: lightning-record-edit-form]

Comment: Can you please add the minimal required code to check the issue?

Comment: Hi Sanket, Please find below

<lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="">
<div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
<div class="slds-col slds-small-size_12-of-12 slds-medium-size_5-of-12 slds-large-size_6-of-12">
<label for="fieldid"><b>Start Date/Time</b></label>
<lightning-input-field ></lightning-input-field>
</div>
<div class="slds-col slds-small-size_12-of-12 slds-medium-size_5-of-12 slds-large-size_6-of-12">
<label for="fieldids"><b>End Date/Time</b></label>
<lightning-input-field > </lightning-input-field>
</div>
</div>
</lightning-record-edit-form>